# Javascript checking if a letter is an uppercase

Tags: javascript, uppercase

I'm transforming a python code to javascript, the point of this code is to check if uppercases and replace it with a hyphen + the lowercase of this same letter.

```js
var string = "zIndex:5,background:transparent,borderRadius:0px,fontSize:8px";

String.prototype.isUpperCase = function() {
    return this.valueOf().toUpperCase() === this.valueOf();
};

function getIndices(string) {
    for (var s in string) {
        if (string[s].isUpperCase()) {
            string = string.replace(string[s], '-' + string[s].toLowerCase())
        }
    }
    return string
}

document.getElementById('default').innerHTML = string;
document.getElementById('tocss').innerHTML = getIndices(string);
```

```html
<div id="default"></div>
<br><hr><br>
<div id="tocss"></div>
```

The problem is that when checking letters it blocks on punctuations & special characters not being able to understand what to do with it, I was wondering if there was a way to ignore CSS punctuations?

```
expeted result, eg.. : borderRadius:0px,fontSize:8px -> border-radius:0px,font-size:8px
```

Comment: don't forget about the turkey problem.

Comment: It's not recommended to extend the prototype.

Comment: @DanielA.White What is it?

Comment: http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression and look for upper case letters only. Then replace with dash and a lower case letter.

```js
var string = 'borderRadius:0px,fontSize:8px';

console.log(string.replace(/[A-Z]/g, s => '-' + s.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: I will adopt this one, seems way more efficiant than mine

Answer (score 1):

Based on @MihaiAlexandru-lonut recommandation, I dropped extending the prototype, works with this function.

```
function isUpperCase(str) {
    return str == str.toUpperCase() && str != str.toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegExp` to replace all uppercase letters with whatever you want

```js
var str = "zIndex:5,background:transparent,borderRadius:0px,fontSize:8px";

const regex = /[A-Z]+/g;


const newStr = str.replace(regex, (match) => `-${match}`.toLowerCase());

console.log('oldStr => ', str)
console.log('newStr => ', newStr)
```